Converting eSignature calls to eNotary calls
I haven’t dug into the eNotary much yet, but one of our teams is looking to implement RON into their workflows.  The contracts are currently sent with the eSignature api utilizing the C# SDK.  My question is how difficult it is to change this to use the eNotary API are there any guides to do this without having to rebuild all the existing code or is it just as simple as enabling the document for notary when I send the API call?
